# docker, interactive brokers gateway, networking and python script exectution

Tags: python, docker, interactive, linode, interactive-brokers

To give a bit of a background, I have been working on an Interactive Brokers python algo using mainly IB gateway to execute python scripts.

Recently I started doing a bit of paper trading running everything locally, without a problem. The issue is, I can not work on python algo while it's running locally.

With that said, my idea is to run the IB gateway on one docker container on the Linode cloud alongside the main algo routine on a separate container (order executions, portfolio management, etc.). The second part of the idea is to be able to connect from my local machine to the IB Gateway docker container (with a different client ID) and be able to interact with the API (of course not submitting orders, but e.g. checking the PnL).

I have managed to set up a docker container with IB Gateway locally and connect to that container with my local pc and execute scripts which encouraged me to try to do the same on the cloud, at least the first part of the idea (2 containers, one with IB gateway, and second with python algo routine)

Needless to mention, this failed miserably, I can not successfully connect to IB gateway from another container. I have tried adding all the local IPs and docker IPs such as 127.0.0.1, 172.17.0.1/16 to IB Gateway, which didn't work

I have pulled the below 2 containers:

https://hub.docker.com/r/mgvazquez/ibgateway

https://hub.docker.com/_/python

if it is helpful to see, below is the result of the docker ps command

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                        COMMAND           CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                                         NAMES
58300d180939   mgvazquez/ibgateway:latest   "/sbin/my_init"   50 minutes ago   Up 23 minutes   0.0.0.0:4002->4002/tcp, :::4002->4002/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5900->5900/tcp, :::5900->5900/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7497->7497/tcp, :::7497->7497/tcp   dckrcmps_gateway_1
```

PS this is the first time I'm dealing with docker and a combination of docker and IB Gateway topic seems to be a bit limited online and Im a bit stuck, I spend 4 days on this without success.

Comment: I recently installed it and it was pretty easy and updated: https://github.com/UnusualAlpha/ib-gateway-docker